# django rest framework how to add entries for multiple tables with one request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add genres to the Genre model at the same time as adding a Movie to the movie model, however I get the following response object when trying to add a Genre entry that doesn't already exist (works fine if it exists in the table already):

```
{'genres': ['Object with genre=Mystery does not exist.']}
```

I thought it should work using the object.get_or_create() in the create() method of the MovieSerializer but it doesn't seem to work.

Also I'm sending data by POST request in the format:

```
{'tmdb_id': 14,
'title': 'some movie',
'release_date': '2011-12-12',
'genres': ['Action', 'Mystery']}
```

not sure if that matters.

Here's the code:

**Views.py**

```
class CreateMovieView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new movie."""
        serializer.save()


class MovieDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

**Models.py**

```
class Genre(models.Model):

    genre = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.genre)


class Movie(models.Model):

    tmdb_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    imdb_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    img_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    runtime = models.CharField(max_length=65, blank=True)
    synopsis = models.TextField(blank=True)
    imdb_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    metascore = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name='genres', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

    genres = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='genre', many=True, queryset=Genre.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Movie
        fields = ('tmdb_id',
                  'imdb_id',
                  'title',
                  'release_date',
                  'img_path',
                  'runtime',
                  'synopsis',
                  'imdb_rating',
                  'metascore',
                  'genres')

def create(self, validated_data):
    genres_data = validated_data.pop('genres')
    movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for genre_name in genres_data:
        genre, created = Genre.objects.get_or_create(genre=genre_name)
        movie.genres.add(genre)

    return movie
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is the error you get, but seems like your'e not using the Views correctly to allow creation of Movie instances.
the [ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) lets you create lists of movies
you should, instead, add a CreateModelMixin to your other view:

```
class MovieDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView,
                       mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

or, even better, use the ModelViewSet:

```
from restframework import viewsets

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ...
```

Comment: I have now implemented the ModelViewSet, however I'm still getting the same response. I now think the problem is that the data is not being serialized correctly. I tried testing it and it seems MovieSerializer does not properly serialize the nested object for genres. When trying to serialize I get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'genre'`

Comment: maybe override the ModelSerializer.to_internal_data() method to get or create the genres and put the new genres ids to the data.
be sure you know exactly how SlugRelatedField functions.